# Tidyquant rolling sharpe ratio using dynamic risk free rate

Tags: rollapply, performanceanalytics, tidyquant

I'm looking to pass the risk free rate dynamically into the PortfolioAnalytics function SharpeRatio.annualized through the mutated PA function rollapply by using tq_mutate.

Edit* At the moment I am unable to roll the time period window of risk free rate along with the portfolio either through a group or column. Example window would be 120 months and would extend for both returns and the risk free rate. As it is written below, I can substitute "Rf =" for a number or equation but not the rolling period. How can I include this rolling risk free rate in the below function?

I have a tibble of monthly time series returns, with one group ("portfolio") containing the RFR set up that looks like this, I also included the RFR as a column "return.rf" to see if that could work as well.

*Note Sharpes in the tibble below do not have RF subtracted*

```
# A tibble: 2,133 x 13
# Groups:   portfolio [9]
   portfolio index         return return.rf Sharpe_12 Sharpe_36 Sharpe_60
   <chr>     <date>         <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 BH        1998-04-30 -0.0142     0.00430        NA        NA        NA
 2 BH        1998-05-29  0.000259   0.00400        NA        NA        NA
 3 BH        1998-06-30 -0.0525     0.00410        NA        NA        NA
 4 BH        1998-07-31 -0.00949    0.00400        NA        NA        NA
 5 BH        1998-08-31  0.000536   0.00430        NA        NA        NA
 6 BH        1998-09-30  0.0486     0.00460        NA        NA        NA
 7 BH        1998-10-30  0.00685    0.00320        NA        NA        NA
 8 BH        1998-11-30 -0.00452    0.00310        NA        NA        NA
 9 BH        1998-12-31  0.00615    0.00380        NA        NA        NA
10 BH        1999-01-29  0.0323     0.00350        NA        NA        NA
```

My code is functioning if I comment out the pass through of Rf:

```
tidy_opt_roll_returns <- tidy_opt.returns %>%    
  tq_mutate(
    # tq_mutate args
    select     = return,
    mutate_fun = rollapply, 
    # rollapply args
    width      = 120,
    align      = "right",
    FUN        = SharpeRatio.annualized,
    # mean args ## commented out next three lines ##
    # Rf         = return.rf,
    # tq_mutate args
    col_rename = "Sharpe_120")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify exactly what your question is.

Comment: Editing the post as it wasn't clear.

Comment: @Venantius How can I include a rolling risk free rate in the  function?